# Dynamic to(URI) in Camel

Tags: java, integration, apache-camel

I'd like configure a Camel route where the `to(uri)` can be specified at runtime.

I tried the following:

```
public class Foo extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        // the URI can point to different hosts
        from("direct:start").to(${someUri}");
    }
}
```

and then

```
ProducerTemplate pt = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
pt.requestBodyAndHeader("direct:start", "someUri", "http://example.com");
```

However the above doesn't work (Camel complains about not having a default Endpoint).

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: I have answered the same question in the following question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071934/camel-http-endpoint-forming-url-dynamically/21327170#21327170

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see these links for reference:

http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

for an example, see this unit test

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/RecipientListTest.java

Comment: I saw `recipientList()` mentioned on the mailing list but didn't have much luck getting it to work. Can you provide an example of what the ProducerTemplate side of things will look like?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question has already been answered, I wanted to share this other option to achieve what you're looking for, in case someone else still wonders how to do it:

There is a new method since Camel 2.16 called "toD" wich basically means a "dynamic to". [Here is the official reference documentation](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html).

```
from("direct:start")
  .toD("${someUri}");
```

In this case, the toD method resolves the argument using the [Simple language](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) wich means you can use any property that the language supports.

You can also take a look at [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36588635/6581856), about that same topic.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used curly braces without the '$' before it.  Here is what I did:

```
{headers.reQueueName} instead of ${headers.reQueueName} for the uri and it worked : 
  <to id="requeue" uri="jmsamq:queue:{headers.reQueueName}"/> here is my implementation    :    


<route id="_throttleRoute">
            <from id="throttleRouteStarter" uri="direct:throttleRouteService"/>
            <log id="_Step_5" message="Camel throttle Route Started"/>
            <log id="_Step_5_1" message="Camel throttle Route is ${headers.next}"/>
            <to id="restThrottleCall" uri="restlet:http://host:port/path"/>
            <process id="throttleRouteProcess" ref="throttleServiceProcessor"/>
            <choice id="_choice2">`enter code here`
                <when id="_when3">
                    <simple>${headers.next} == 'requeue'</simple>   
                    <to id="requeue" uri="jmsamq:queue:{headers.reQueueName}"/>
                    <log id="_Step_wait1" message="ReQueue sending to ${headers.reQueueName}"/>
                </when>
                <when id="_when4">
                    <simple>${headers.next} == 'process'</simple>
                    <log id="_logNext" message="Invoking Next Work Unit ${headers.next}"/>
                    <process id="jBPMRouteProcess" ref="jBPMRouteProcessor"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise id="_otherwise2">
                    <log id="_log5" loggingLevel="WARN" message="Next for orderId: ${headers.orderid} not found"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </route>
```