# camel http endpoint forming url dynamically

Tags: http, url, dynamic, apache-camel, endpoint

Guys I am trying to use

```
{
from("direct:a").to (someUrl).processor(new Processor(){

   @Override
   public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception
   {
      // do something
   }

});


where someUrl is of the type http://xyz.com/{id}?test=<value1>&test1=<value2>
}
```

and this url will change on every request to the route.

What i have already tried. Passing params as headers and try to access in the route using the header("test") and using ${in.header.test} both doesn't seem to work.

any suggestions will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this FAQ about dynamic to endpoints in Camel: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Read the FAQ again! You cannot use dynamic values in TO, you should use RECIPIENT LIST instead.

Comment: I know the question is already got answered but will it be a right way of using the camel (is it a anti-pattern)? Because eip not mean the same usage here: enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/RecipientList.html

Comment: It is certainly not an anti pattern. The EIP is to route a message to a dynamic list of recipients. Which is what the Camel implementation does. And a list of recipients can be 1..n recipients.

Comment: thanks @claus. Is there any other way to make a remote (not exposed by us) RESTful calls having path-params.

I guess only other comes to my mind is setting HTTP_URI header which will override the to endpoint's value. 

Which one is better in terms of ideal camel usage.

Comment: See the Camel components as there is also some REST components among them: http://camel.apache.org/components

Comment: is there a way to make <from uri="" also dynamic ??

Comment: Updated link https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 6):

From camel 2.16 you can do things like this -

```
from("direct:start")   
   .toD("${header.foo}");
```

Refer : http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html

Comment: any clue for calling dynamic https url. For e.g: toD("https://${header.foo}/bar")

Answer (score 2):

You can use camel property place holder

http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

```
<camelContext trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <propertyPlaceholder location="config/AuditJMSConfig.properties" id="properties" />
    <route id="crudRoute">
        <from uri="activeMQ:queue:{{speedwing.activemq.auditqueue}}/>
    </route>                                                                                    where speedwing.activemq.auditqueue is the property name defined in the peroperties file.
```

you can use the same for `<to uri="" also`

Comment: Well this is "semi-dynamic" - when camel is initialized the property is used and from this time _<to uri_  has constant value. But question was about dynamic endpoint on EACH request..